# How to decide between rules and property chains in OWL 2?

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, rdfs

In OWL, we can define the relation hasUncle using rules (SWRL or DL-safe) or property chains.

By property chains:
hasUncle is equivalent to "hasParent o hasBrother"

By rules, we can do this:
hasParent(?x,?p), hasBrother(?p,?u) -> hasUncle(?x,?u)

What are the advantages of both approaches? When should I use one of them instead of the other?

Comment: it's straightforward: rules are more expressive (you have variables, built-in functions, etc.) but not part of OWL but SWRL which isn't supported by all OWL reasoners and can make reasoning even more complex. An OWL property chain axiom on the other hand is part of the OWL 2 standard, thus, any fully compliant reasoner will take this into account.

Comment: But we could use DL-safe rules. In this case, the distincttion is not obvous, in my opinion.

Comment: You're missing up different things here. DL-safe rules is a subset of SWRL that keeps reasoning decidable. Even here the same holds, you can use variables and a reasoner has to support it.